# radio button looks checked on hover event?

Tags: events, radiobuttonlist

Is it possible to control the display of a radio button via mouse over events?

The goal would be so that it looks checked when the mouse is over and unchecked when the mouse leaves. But it only gets checked when it is clicked just like rating.

Comment: have you tried anything? if so please share so we can help you...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$("input:radio").hover(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
}, function(){
        //MouseOut event
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
}).click(function(){
    //Unbind the hover event for all the radio buttons
    $("input:radio").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
    //Check clicked radio button
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/B6qBz/

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with it a little bit, i came up with this...check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/n8CdM/1/) and see if does the trick...oh and since you did not mentioned any particular language so i achieved this with jQuery...hope it helps

This may not be the perfect solution but it definitely meets the requirements:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="cols" id="col-1" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="cols" id="col-2" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="cols" id="col-3" />
```

JS:

```
var clicked = false;
var clickedId;

$('input').click(function () {
    clicked = true;
    clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
});
$('input').hover(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
}, function () {
    if (clicked === true) {
        $('#' + clickedId).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```